# Show sliding div at page load

Tags: html, css

I have a div fixed on the left of my page that starts partially hidden off the page and then slides smoothly in on mouseover. What I'd like to do is have the div be fully visible at page load, then slide away after a few seconds, then have its normal mouseover functionality.

The div in question:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div id="calculator">Novated Lease Calculator</div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#calculator {
    width: 297px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url("../img/calculator-button.png") no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    top: 218px;
    left: -247px;
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#calculator:hover {
    left: 0;
}
```

I'd like to use a CSS solution if possible; however javascript is OK if there's no alternative.

Comment: `text-indent: -9999px;` ? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: It serves to hide the overlying text, so that only the background image is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through **pure css**, although with kind of a hack. Try this

***CSS***

```
#calculator {
    width: 297px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: #f00;
    position: fixed;
    top: 218px;
    left: -247px;
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    animation: slideOnLoad 1s 1;
    -webkit-animation: slideOnLoad 1s 1;
}

@keyframes slideOnLoad
{
    0% {left:-247px;}
    0.1% {left:0px;}
    100% {left:-247px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideOnLoad
{
    0% {left:-247px;}
    0.1% {left:0px;}
    100% {left:-247px;}
}

#calculator:hover {
    left: 0;
}
```

**working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T5KLH/)**

To explain what I did. I've used animation css3 property to animate your element one time on load. A bit of a hack here is the 0-0.1% solution. That keeps your element in the right place, then move it to left:0 fast like a wind, and start smooth animation to hide this element again. The rest is your hover solution.

You can play with timings as much as you want. If you want your element to stay a bit longer - just add animation step at 20% {left:0px;}

**Beware that, css3 animate don't work on old browsers like IE9. Check list of browsers [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)**

Comment: *sidenote*: watch out the old browsers (e.g. IE9)

Answer (score 0):

```
#calculator {
width: 297px;
height: 60px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url("../img/calculator-button.png") no-repeat;
position: fixed;
top: 218px;
left: 0;
z-index: 999;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function onload() {
$("#calculator").css("left", "-247px");
}
```

I didn't test it but if not mistaken, this is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this.if you want to slide up and down then you can use this below code

```
$(document.ready(function(){
     $('div').mouseover(function(){
           $(this).slideDown('slow');
     });
     $('div').mouseout(function(){
           $(this).slideUp('slow');
     });
});
```

otherwise you can check this js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumaranantha/Wtfpx/2/

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag in the question.

Comment: yes, there is no tag of jquery but he tol us however javascript is OK if there's no alternative.@kamilkp

Comment: **javascript** alternative, not necesairly jQuery.

Comment: i dont find any slide effect using pure javascript so i used jquery.if you find any any slider effect then just tell us.i would happy to learn something new.@kamilkp

Comment: if there is no jQuery tag , it doesn't mean we shouldn't answer in it. we should open to all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onload = function(){
    var calc = document.getElementById('calculator');
    calc.style.left = '-247px';
    setTimeout(function(){
       calc.style.left = '';
    }, 2000); // few seconds e.g. 2 s
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8c2Ua/)

Just add this to your code

```
#calculator {
width: 297px;
height: 60px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: #eaeaea;
position: fixed;
top: 218px;
left: -247px;
z-index: 999;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;

animation-name: slide;
animation-duration:5s; /* adjust the tming accordingly for how long the slide should stay */ 
animation-delay:0.5s;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

-webkit-animation-name: slide;
-webkit-animation-duration:5s; /* adjust the tming accordingly for how long the slide should stay */ 
-webkit-animation-delay:0.5s;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}

@keyframes slide {
  0%   { left:-247px;}
  50%   { left:0px;}
  100%   { left:-247px;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide  {

  0%   { left:-247px;}
  50%   { left:0px;}
  100%   { left:-247px;} 

}

#calculator:hover {
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 calculator{ left:-247px; }
 #calculator:hover{ left:0; }
```